# Rewrite URL from HTTP to HTTPS in IIS for specific domains

Tags: windows, web-server, web-hosting, iis-8.5, web.config

I need to make a global rule that rewrites all `http://example.com/` to `https://example.com/`. I host multiple domains and my attempts either don't work or work on all domains.

I put this in my `applicationHost.config`:

```
<globalRules>
  <rule name="Rewrite test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" />
  </rule>
</globalRules>

<globalRules>
  <rule name="kommunetv SSL">
    <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://(.*\.kommunetv.no)(/?.*)" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{C:1}{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
</globalRules>
```

Tried various match patterns and also attempts with `{HTTP_HOST}` conditions. Hoping for some input :)

Comment: If you want a global rule, but then only apply that to certain sites, you can add conditions with `{HTTP_HOST}`, you said you already done that but you don't show what you have done and how it behaved.

Comment: You're right, a bit lazy. I updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

`<globalRules>` in `applicationHost.config` apply to the entire server - all domains.

> ```
> <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
>     <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
> </conditions>
> <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true"/>
> ```

This only checks for `{HTTPS}`, so yes, this will redirect *all* domains.

> ```
> <conditions>
>     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://(.*\.kommunetv.no)(/?.*)" />
> </conditions>
> <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{C:1}{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
> ```

The `HTTP_HOST` variable contains only the hostname from the request (ie. the value of the HTTP `Host` header). It does not contain the scheme or URL-path. So, the above condition will never match and the rule will do nothing. If it did match then it would create a redirect loop as you need to also check the `HTTPS` state.

You need to check both `HTTPS` and `HTTP_HOST`. For example, something like:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" />
```